# Why won't my onclick event display my JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I'm new to JS and JSON, and am taking a class right now in it. For our project, we have to write a JSON file and display it using a button and JS. I have been staring at this for hours and thought I would give up and search for help.

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
  "id": "Pavlov's Dog",
  "dateOfExhibition": "2018-07-08T22:00:00.000Z",
  "address": [],
  "street": "Bergmannstrasse 29",
  "city": "Berlin",
  "country": "Deutschland",
  "zip": "10473"
}
```

Here is my JS:

```
(function () {


var url = 'http://localhost/Advanced_Web/Final_Project/data/exhibitions.json';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
button.onclick = function () {
request.open('GET', url);
    if (request.status == 200) {

        var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var data = '<ul>';

        data += '</ul>';

        $('#exhibitions').html(data);

    } else {
        alert('An error has occurred.');
    }
};

})();
```

and a snippet from my HTML:

```
    </nav>

<!-- JSON TO UNORDERED LIST -->
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
<div id="exhibitions"></div>

    <footer class="footer">
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what error are you getting in the console?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the json, besides assigning it to a var.

Comment: after implementing Quentin's post, I received: Uncaught TypeError: request.addEventHandler is not a function

Comment: @stefsrieder check it out with jquery! as you are already using it, I think it would be an easier approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing the status as soon as you have opened the request. You need to:

1. Actually send the request
2. Wait for a response

---

You are taking a string of JSON, converting it to a JavaScript object and then *ignoring it*

---

It looks like you are trying to bind the click handler to the button before the button exists (and you are using the dubious practice of assuming that the button will generate a global variable matching its id.

---

Something along the lines of this should work:

```js
addEventListener("load", set_up_click_handler);

function set_up_click_handler() {
  var url = 'http://localhost/Advanced_Web/Final_Project/data/exhibitions.json';
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", click_handler);

  function click_handler(event) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.addEventListener("load", response_handler);
    request.send();
  };

  function response_handler() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      var json = this.responseText;
      var data = JSON.parse(json);
      var list = $('<ul />');
      for (var item in data) {
        list.append(
          $("<li />").text(item + ": " + data[item])
        );
      }
      $('#exhibitions').append(list);
    } else {
      alert('An error has occurred.');
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This is the error I received after implementing these changes: Uncaught TypeError: request.addEventHandler is not a function

Comment: Should have been `addEventListener`

Comment: hmm for some reason still isn't working. Now getting this message:ajax.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined

Comment: Should have been `this`, I missed one when I moved it to another function.

Comment: Hi @quentin, every time I click on my button, the <ul> displays itself again. So if I click the button 3 times, the <ul> displays itself 3 times on my page. Do I need to add a request at the end of the page to prevent this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually initiating the request with a call to the `send` method.

(function () {

```
 var url = 'http://localhost/Advanced_Web/Final_Project/data/exhibitions.json';
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 button.onclick = function () {
     request.open('GET', url);

     request.send(null);  //  << YOU FORGOT THIS
 }
```

Also, you can't jump right into the handling of the response right after making the request. Since it is an AJAX call, you don't know when the response will come back. You need to set up a success callback:

```
     request.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(){

        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == 200) {

            var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var data = '<ul>';

            data += json + '</ul>';

            $('#exhibitions').html(data);

            } else {
              alert('An error has occurred.');
            }
     });
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend new learners to use `readystatechange`, as it is outdated. There is a perfectly simple `load` event.

Comment: readystatechange is not outdated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange). I would argue that onload is outdated and addEventListener should be used.

Comment: I'd avoid readystate because it will fire repeatedly until the content is loaded, so if you are waiting for it to load you have to keep aborting your function.

Comment: @Quentin readystate will not fire "repeatedly" until the content is loaded. It will fire when the readystate changes (which is not repeatedly). You don't have to "abort" the function, you just test for a successfully completed request. Also, I'm not implying it's better than load, I'm just answering the question. What readystatechange does do is give you a central location to take full control of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not taking the asynchronous aspect of `XMLHttpRequest` into consideration. This bit of code shows that:

```
request.open('GET', url);
if (request.status == 200) {
```

Also, you forgot the call to `.send()`, and adding the response data into your html.

Instead of instantly checking the `request.status`, you need to **wait** for the request to finish. This is done by adding a function to the `onload` property of the `XMLHttpRequest` (version 2) object.

```
request.open('GET', url);
request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status == 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var data = '<ul>';
        data += /* some parts of the json object */;
        data += '</ul>';
    }
};
request.send();
```

Comment: he also needs to concatenate the parsed json to the data appended to the DOM `data = "<ul>" + json + "</ul>"`

Comment: Thanks. Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use jquery to make this request, which as a beginner may be easier than the more verbose vanilla javascript approach.

```
(function () {    
    $("button").on("click", function(){
       $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
         var list = $('<ul />');
         for(prop in data){
           list.append($("<li />").text(data[prop]));
          }
          $('#exhibitions').append(list);
          }).fail(function() {
            alert( "failed" );
       })
     })
 })();
```

Answer (score -1):

Where's your click Event? You never `request.send()` or do anything with your `json` var. Below are working get and post XMLHttpRequest function examples, that can take Objects as their first argument.

```
var doc = docmuent, bod = doc.body;
function E(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
function phpize(obj, ignore){
  var r = [];
  for(var i in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
      var p = ignore ? ignore+'['+i+']' : i;
      var v = obj[i];
      var s = typeof v === 'object' ? phpize(v, p) : encodeURIComponent(p)+'='+encodeURIComponent(v);
      r.push(s);
    }
  }
  return r.join('&');
}
function get(send, where, success, context){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest || new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  var c = context || this;
  x.open('GET', where.replace(/(\\|\/)$/,'')+'?'+phpize(send));
  x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
      if(success)success.call(c, eval('('+x.responseText+')'));
    }
  }
  x.send();
}
function post(send, where, success, context){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest || new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  var c = context || this;
  x.open('POST', where); x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
      if(success)success.call(c, eval('('+x.responseText+')'));
    }
  }
  x.send(phpize(send));
}
E('button').onclick = function(){
  get({sendProp1:'send value 1'}, 'http://localhost/Advanced_Web/Final_Project/data/exhibitions.json', function(){
    // do stuff now
  }, this);
});
```